# Symfony2 -> validation -> repeated field

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

Is there a way to display validation errors for **both** repeated fields? For now, error displays only near first one.
I want to get this effect:

Password:             |___________|
                              passwords are not exac!
Retype password: |___________|
                              passwords are not exac!
But now i get this:
Password:             |___________|
                              passwords are not exac!
Retype password: |___________|

Answer (score 0):

i also have a same solution and i solved it using post_submit event in the formbuilder.

```
$builder->add('email')->add('pass1')->add('pass2');

$myExtraFieldValidator = function(FormEvent $event){
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $pass1 = $form->get('pass1')->getData();
            $pass2 = $form->get('pass2')->getData();
            if ($pass1!=$pass2) {
                $form['pass1']->addError(new FormError("yout error message"));
$form['pass2']->addError(new FormError("yout error message"));
            }
        };
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, $myExtraFieldValidator);
```

Comment: thanks for answer! this is good solution but i thought there will be more 'elegant' way to make this, anyway its valuable information for me and thanks!

Comment: Yes Offcoues, You can do this stuff either in twig, controller level, form level or even entity level. but the best is to have this validation on front end that include twig and forms.